# simplemodal - IE8 $.support.boxModel is not NULL and no object

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, simplemodal

I try to use the simplmodal script from: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

I got this error $.support.boxModel is not NULL.. in IE8.

jquery.simplemodal-1.3.4.min.js?F

This is my implementation scipt.. what I have to change to avoid this error?

```
function loadIframe(url){
  $.modal('<iframe src="' + url + '" height="700px" width="600px" scrolling="no">', {
    containerCss:{
        backgroundColor:"#fff",
        borderColor:"#333",
    },
    overlayClose:true,
    opacity:70,
    overlayCss: {
        backgroundColor:"#000"
    },
    onOpen: function (dialog) {
    dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
        dialog.container.toggleClass("preloader"); 
        dialog.data.hide();
        dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () {
          dialog.container.toggleClass("preloader");
          dialog.data.slideDown('slow');
        });
        });
    },
    onClose: function (dialog) {
    dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function () {
        dialog.container.slideUp('slow', function () {
            dialog.overlay.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $.modal.close(); // must call this!
            });
        });
      });
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").click(function(){
  var baseurl = location.host;
  var url = $(this).attr("target");
  var url = 'http://' + baseurl + url;
  loadIframe(url);
  });
});
```

Comment: Im guessing here but either this is a problem with IE8 or with the version of jQuery. Make sure you have the right version of jQuery for the plugin, and see if your code works in another browser ...

Answer (score 1):

I have a fix tht I need to release. Until then, you can edit SimpleModal and change:

```
$.support.boxModel
```

to:

```
$.boxModel
```

-Eric

Comment: Thanks Eric, I have the same issue with IE7 and this fixed it.  Btw, love your plugin, it is so easy to use.